# Approach on Loading angular JS templates for a multi tenant Application?

Tags: angularjs

I have a SPA Angular Application. I need to hide or show certain sections of a particular template based on the Tenant ID of the logged in user. The problem is, Tenant A may want to hide some controls and add some extra attrbutes, where as Tenant B may have a altogther separate requirement on the same page.

I may end up writing lots of If else on the same template and may also need to modify controllers to handle conditions of various Tenants.If number of tenants increases, The solution becomes messier.

One more Approach is to introduce redundancy and make separate copies of templates for each Tenant and maintain a configuration mapping of tenant to Templates. This way code is segregated.but still Controllers would be same. If I duplicate controllers, Even test suite has to be duplicated and will take time if Test suite is ran for every tenant.

Can somebody give me a better approach, how can this be achieved in a optimal way ?

Comment: have an exactly similar situation in my project, did you find the better solution? please update your experience and how did you solve in your project, it would be a lot of helpful. Thanks.